# C# record struct implicit conversion operator not working

Tags: c#, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a readonly record struct with five properties and two implicit operators.

```cs
readonly record struct Puzzle ()
{
    public required string Input { get; init; }

    public required string Sample { get; init; }

    public string? P2Sample { get; init; } = null;

    public required Func<string, int> Part1 { get; init; }

    public required Func<string, int> Part2 { get; init; }

    public static implicit operator Puzzle ((string input, string p1Sample, string? p2Sample, Func<string, int> part1, Func<string, int> part2) value) => new()
    {
        Input = value.input,
        Sample = value.p1Sample,
        P2Sample = value.p2Sample,
        Part1 = value.part1,
        Part2 = value.part2
    };

    public static implicit operator Puzzle ((string input, string sample, Func<string, int> part1, Func<string, int> part2) value) => 
        (value.input, value.sample, null, value.part1, value.part2);
}
```

However, the second conversion operator (four element tuple) doesn't work at all - as if the compiler doesn't know it exists.

When I try to use it like this:

```cs
new Puzzle[] {
    (Inputs.Day1Input, Inputs.Day1_1Sample, Inputs.Day1_2Sample, Day1_1.ExtractSum, Day1_2.ExtractSum),
    (Inputs.Day2Input, Inputs.Day2Sample, Day2.MinColorPowers, Day2.MinColorPowers)
}
```

The first element works perfectly fine, but the second one throws an error - `CS8135: Tuple with 4 elements cannot be converted to type 'Puzzle'.`

I have clearly defined an operator to convert a four-element tuple to `Puzzle` - so why does this happen?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What are the types of `Day2.MinColorPowers`, `Day2.MinColorPowers` etc?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: it works fine here. The most likely reason is that the types of the arguments you're passing (which you haven't specified in your question) don't match the types of the tuple members in your implicit conversion

Comment: As an aside, this is horrible, unreadable and unmaintainable. Just create constructors with the signatures you want, and call `new Puzzle[] { new(...), new(...) }`. That will have the bonus of telling you exactly what parameter has the wrong type.

Comment: @canton7 You're right about the code quality... This was an incredibly simple mistake, and it would have been much easier to fix if the code was better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try this code, it compiles just fine:

```
    Func<string, int> ExtractSum = int.Parse;
    var puzzle = new Puzzle[] {
        ("", "", "", ExtractSum, ExtractSum),
        ("", "", MinColorPowers, MinColorPowers)
    };
    int MinColorPowers(string s) => int.Parse(s);
```

But if I change the signature of the MinColorPowers function, I get the same error you're getting:

```
    float MinColorPowers(string s) => int.Parse(s);
```

Chances are, the method you're passing in doesn't match the delegate signature for your tuple type. Try explicitly casting the delegate arguments you're passing in to the types you're expecting. It will probably give you a more informative error.